# Intel max 10 dimensions - datasheet & BSDL mismatch

Tags: eaglecad, intel-fpga, packages, dimensions, max10

TL;DR: The BSD file from Intel doesn't match the datasheet. What are the right dimensions?

BSD: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/others/support/devices/bsdl/10M02SCM153.bsd

Datasheet: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/packaging/04r00471-00.pdf

So I was drawing a max 10 (10M02SCM153) and afterwards saw that you can download the BSD files from Intel (see link above). I crosschecked the imported BSD drawing and the Intel datasheet and came to the conclusion that they don't match. 
[image: datasheet-BSD]

The number and the layout of the pins match.

According to Intel and the datasheet their BSC informations are in milimeters: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/solutions/rd07152011_585.html

I have a 10M50DAF484 besides me and measured his dimensions and crosschecked with the datasheet: Everything Ok.

Then I checked the BSD file of the 10M50DAF484 and the dimensions where ok too.

In the case of the 10M02SCM153, which dimensions are the correct ones?

Comment: If BSC is 2mm the silk outline is 1mm larger than the package.

Comment: @Jasen If BSC is 2mm than it would add up for the 10M02SCM153 specification, but than the 10M50DAF484 dimensions wouldn't add up because they match with BSC 1mm.
Have you ever seen a datasheet where BSC /= 1[insert your unit here]?

Comment: unit here seems to be 2mm - feed that in an both pictures agree except for 1mm on the package outline. e=0.5 BSC seems odd,  but so is a pachage drawing that give the size of the package, maybe they were a month late...

Comment: Ok, 10M50 has e=1.0 too, so 16x16 should be okay?
But is there any way to recognize, that BSC should be read as 2mm? If I crosscheck with the 10M50 dimensions than all units must be multiplied by 2.

Comment: no, I can't see any way to get the over-all size information from that data sheet, I was meaning "a package drawing that does NOT give size is unusual, and this one a month late to be an April 1st prank"  Alterra has defined BSC as 1mm.  comments in the BSC say the same.  are you certain that Eagle grid pitch is 0.5mm and not 0.25 ?

Comment: I am sure about the measurements on the picture above. I noticed the difference because i made the footprint myself and updated it with the imported BSDL file from Intel. The only conclusion i can come to is, that the datasheet is wrong.

Comment: The datasheet will be correct. Notice the table even states that the unit is "millimeters". Don't know why there is a mismatch in the imported data.

Comment: How did you import the footprint?

Comment: I used the import function in the library editor and  imported the linked file. Eagle defines the values, like diameter pad grid and body width when importing the file.
I can change the values to get the 8mm, but what is still confusing me is that the 10M50 was generated with the right values.

Comment: Probably: Because the pin grid of the 10M50 device is 1mm and with 22 pins you get 22mm, 1 mm for the package => 23mm.
My guess is, that eagle doesn't read any dimension values from the file and just takes default values (1mm pad grid) and the 10M50 is pure coincidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasheet will be correct. Notice the table states that the unit is "millimeters".

I dont know why the Eagle dimensions are wrong. There doesn't seem to be any dimensional data in the BSD file, so I'm not sure how Eagle can interpret it.

In fact, in the BSD file it says at the top:

```
Package : 8 mm 153 MBGA
```

Which matches the 8mm of the datasheet.